# Can't uninstall AVG Antivirus 2011

Tags: windows, uninstall, avg-antivirus

When I try to uninstall AVG Antivirus, I get the message

> Associated with Another Application

I looked at "Task Manager" → "Processes" and stopped all related processes, but it didn't help.

How can I uninstall the application?

Comment: What is the _exact_ text of the error?

Comment: Did you try rebooting?

Comment: Did you use their Removal Tool? On my Google, I get http://www.avg.com/ca-en/utilities and I can download the removal tool there.